# creating a conda environment fails on MacOS: ResolvePackageNotFound

Tags: python, macos, conda, miniconda

I want to set up [stable-diffusion](https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion) on my machine (M1 MacOS), based on [these instructions](https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/how-to-run-stable-diffusion-locally-to-generate-images/), I'm running:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh 
bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh
```

I accept the license and confirm the installation location, everything looks good.

Then, when I want to create an environment with `conda env create -f environment.yaml`, I run into this error:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - python=3.8.5
  - cudatoolkit=11.3
  - pip=20.3
  - torchvision=0.12.0
```

The environment.yaml file contains this:

```
name: ldm
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8.5
  - pip=20.3
  - cudatoolkit=11.3
  - pytorch=1.11.0
  - torchvision=0.12.0
  - numpy=1.19.2
  - pip:
    - albumentations==0.4.3
    - diffusers
    - opencv-python==4.1.2.30
    - pudb==2019.2
    - invisible-watermark
    - imageio==2.9.0
    - imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.2
    - pytorch-lightning==1.4.2
    - omegaconf==2.1.1
    - test-tube>=0.7.5
    - streamlit>=0.73.1
    - einops==0.3.0
    - torch-fidelity==0.3.0
    - transformers==4.19.2
    - torchmetrics==0.6.0
    - kornia==0.6
    - -e git+https://github.com/CompVis/taming-transformers.git@master#egg=taming-transformers
    - -e git+https://github.com/openai/CLIP.git@main#egg=clip
    - -e .
```

Where do go from here? I was under the impression that conda would install the required dependencies, but I guess not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The central issue is trying to create a native **osx-arm64** environment.

First, use `conda-forge` channel instead of `defaults`.<sup>**1**</sup> Second, native PyTorch packages are only available for `pytorch >=1.12` and `torchvision >=0.13`. Third, no Apple Silicon systems come with nVidia cards, so `cudatoolkit` is inappropriate - remove it.

There are probably more issues, but that's a start. Also, you should probably [read this thread](https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion/issues/25) closely.

---

<sub>**[1]**: You would have been better off installing [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) like Mambaforge, not Miniconda. Conda Forge has been supporting **osx-arm64** for nearly two years, so has a much deeper catalog of available packages than `defaults` channel, which only added support in May.</sub>

Comment: thanks @merv I appreciate the answer - as you expected, more trouble started appearing, so I'm now using another tutorial specifically for MacOS users: https://dev.to/craigmorten/setting-up-stable-diffusion-for-macos-1igl (involves using a fork of the stable diffusion repo)